# Show image from database in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, image

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC web development.

I wanted to show the image in img tag in razor view from SQL server database.

In my model the image is stored as array of bytes:

```
public class Business
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public byte[] LogoImage { get; set; }

    }
```

In controller I'm getting the image data from db [varbinary(MAX)] column:

```
...
    LogoImage = (byte[])reader["LogoImage"]
...
```

In view I'm having a standard details template where I'm putting the following code:

```
@{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(model.LogoImage);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
}
<img src='@imgSrc' style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px;" />
```

So, I'm really struggled in the razor view, if treat the one, the other error happens. The other properties are shown except image.

Could someone suggest how do I show the image in razor view?
Is it good to populate image as img src='...long data...'?
How to pass or access an array from model? Do I have to convert it to string as @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LogoImage)?

Comment: What error do you get? The code should work if you replace "model.Image" with "model.LogoImage" and if the image actually has gif format.

Comment: @NineBerry Thnx for quick response, I've changed to the LogoImage (typo). So rn I can't access model array as model.LogoImage says 'model' doesn't exist in the current context. Should I access as Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LogoImage) ??

Comment: You need to spell Model with a capital M. Html.DisplayFor doesn't know how to handle images

Comment: OMG, thanks it was giving me Null Exception initially, im gonna manage it. THANKS A LOT @NineBerry you saved my day. Put your comments as answer ill mark it. thanks for the guide it was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

you can show image from this code

```
<img style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px;" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(imgSrc))">
```

Comment: the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Make an Action that returns the contents of your image and point to his action from the img tag src. This action should use the File result type.
2. From you controller, encode your image as base64 and use data in your src. Maybe here, the problem that you have is that you need to use `@Html.Raw(imgSrc)` so it does not escape the base64 string.

If your image is big, maybe the first option is better. Also, data urls might not be supported in all browsers.